# Update Notification through Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am creating an app that has a constant notification that reports stats to the user.  Every 10 minute, I update the stats in the app, then update the notification.  The problem is, the stats update in the app, but the notification does not update until I open the app.  I call the same method to update the notification regardless of if the app is open or if it is called through a service.

Is there something special I have to do because it's running through a service?

Service Code (again, this works fine):

```
Thread.sleep(((10 /* minutes */) * 60 * 1000));
Handler handler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        OverviewFragment.refresh(getApplicationContext());

    }
};
handler.post(runnable);
System.out.println("Updated values through service.");
```

Refresh Code (for notification):

```
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_white)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_old))
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContent(remoteViews)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

Comment: Have you not called startForeground() ?

Comment: In the service class when you set the notification. Check it out here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,android.app.Notification)